# installed windows 7 64-bit on a intel core duo machine

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, cpu

If I installed Windows 7 64-bit on an Intel core duo machine, will this cause any problems?

It's a 3 year-old computer, so I'm not sure if it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a Core **2** Duo or Core Duo?

If it's a Core 2 Duo it's fine.

If it's a Core Duo, it won't work, because the Core Duo is only a 32-bit processor.

Comment: On top of this answer, see my answer here to find if your exact model does support 64 bit http://superuser.com/questions/59574/can-most-intel-processors-run-64-bit-windows-7/59582#59582

Answer (score 0):

You should also check that 64 bit drivers are available for your internal components (graphics, network card, etc).  Check out the microsoft site for tested components and I think they also have a downloadable tool that will check your machine for Win7 suitability.